# React Native SectionList Split Dates

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I need to reformat my object of dates and I have an array of dates in such format:

```
  Object {
    "FREETIME": "2021-04-19 11:30:00",
  },
  Object {
    "FREETIME": "2021-04-19 12:00:00",
  },
  Object {
    "FREETIME": "2021-04-20 12:30:00",
  },
  Object {
    "FREETIME": "2021-04-21 12:50:00",
  },
```

and I would want to render them in section list like this:

```
const DATA = [
  {
    title: "2021-04-19",
    data: ["11:30:00", "12:00:00"]
  },
  {
    title: "2021-04-20",
    data: ["12:30:00"]
  },
  {
    title: "2021-04-21",
    data: ["12:50:00"]
  },
];
```

so what I do is first split the array of `FREETIME` by days and times:

```
const dates = data.map((item) => item.FREETIME.split(" "));
```

then I get unique days for section header of `SectionList`:

```
    function onlyUnique(value, index, self) {
        return self.indexOf(value) === index;
    }
    const days = dates.map((item) => item[0]).filter(onlyUnique);
```

and then I try to construct new object DATA with days and corresponding times but fail at mapping the times correctly:

```
    const DATA = days.map((dayHeader) => ({
        title: dayHeader,
        data: //don't know how to map it properly here
    }));
```

What am I doing it wrong or is there another approach to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is one method of doing the job with `Array.prototype.reduce`

```js
const arrayOfObjectDates  = [
    {
        "FREETIME": "2021-04-19 11:30:00",
    },
    {
        "FREETIME": "2021-04-19 12:00:00",
    },
    {
        "FREETIME": "2021-04-20 12:30:00",
    },
    {
        "FREETIME": "2021-04-21 12:50:00",
    }
];

const DATA = arrayOfObjectDates.reduce((op, { FREETIME }) => {
    var [date, time] = FREETIME.split(" "), { result, index } = op;
    if (index.hasOwnProperty(date)) {
        result[index[date]].data.push(time);
    } else {
        index[date] = result.length;
        result.push({ title: date, data: [time] });
    }
    return op;
}, { result: [], index: {} }).result;

console.log(DATA)
```